# Need Help Setting Cell's TextLabel From NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsdictionary

So I have an NSDictionary with 4 objects in it.  Each of these objects then has 2 properties, `name` and `date`

I can list out all the data by logging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your sample code is inside of this method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

If not, that is your first problem.

Right now, you are probably sequentially setting each cell to have *every* title one by one, until it gets to the end of the list.  All of the cells have the same title because they all have the last title in the list.

You should drop the for-loop and use this instead:

```
NSDictionary *object = [objects objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSString *title = [object objectForKey:@"title"];
NSString *date = [object objectForKey:@"publishedDate"];
cell.textLabel.text  = title;
cell.detailTextLabel.text  = date;
```